# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, faraday

I have Rails API server hosted on Heroku, which makes an asynchronous POST request to a callback url specified in an initial API request by the client.

I have a problem when I try to POST to one of my clients' webapp over SSL.

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new('https://subdomain.some_client.com', ssl: { ca_file: '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' })
connection.get '/test'
```

The following throws an error:

```
Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

However, if I post to another server over HTTPS, for example google, it works fine

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new('https://www.google.com', ssl: { ca_file: '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' })
connection.get '/'
```

Does this mean the fault is on the client's SSL configuration? and if so, how can I assist them in debugging the problem?

UPDATE:

I can cURL POST to the client's webapp without problems, it's only when I do it through ruby's HTTP libraries it fails

Much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 19):

My guess is that there is a problem with the SSL cert for your client's web app. Perhaps there is a certificate that is out of date or invalid. You could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089644/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ssl-digital-certificate-is-valid-without-installi).

If you need to get around this (but probably **not a good permanent solution**, because of the potential security hole) you should be able to turn off the certificate verification by putting this before Bundler.require in your application.rb:

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: I tried that and it works, but it is obviously not suitable for a production environment

Comment: This test shows you are missing an intermediate or root cert in your ca-certificates.crt file.  Are you still needing an answer?

Comment: If the cert is out of date or invalid, curl would have reported similar error.

Comment: Variant if you get the "already initialized constant" warning: use `OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER)` before ([example code](https://gist.github.com/siruguri/66926b42a0c70ef7119e)).

Comment: @RodrigoM did you mean to ask the Tarlen? Since he wasn't tagged he may not have sen your comment

Comment: If you're using the Net::HTTP library, you have to do this instead: `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` [reference](https://blog.engineyard.com/ruby-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: You can put `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` in your config/environments/development.rb instead of in config/application.rb. That keeps it out of your production environment.